# how to secure routes laravel-5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-eloquent-resource

hi I wants that only admin can access the filecontroller route, or user can't access by typing URL:

these are routes:

```
  Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth']], function(){
     Route::get('/', function () {
       return view('welcome');
     });

     Route::get('/home', function(){
   if (Auth::user()->admin == 0) {
    return view('home');
   } else {
    $users['users'] = \App\User::all();
    return view('layouts.master', $users);
   }
     });

     Route::resource('file','FileController');

  });
```

User can't access Route::resource('file','FileController'); if he knows URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware)

The following command creates new Middleware called Admin

```
php artisan make:middleware Admin
```

This creates a file called Admin.php within the app/Http/Middleware directory that looks like

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Admin {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin() )
        {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('home');

    }

}
```

You then need to add the Admin Middleware to your app/Http/Kernel.php file

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
    'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
    'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
    'admin' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Admin', // this line right here
];
```

Add the Admin Middleware to a route.

```
 Route::resource('file','FileController')->middleware(Admin::class)
```

Finally you need to add the isAdmin method we created above to your User model to check whether or not the user is an Admin.

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'is_admin' => 'boolean',
    ];

    public function isAdmin()
    {
        return $this->is_admin;
    }
}
```

Comment: in previous middleware m using this:  if(auth()->check() && $request->user()->admin == 0){
            return redirect()->guest('home');
        }
        return $next($request); but now this line gives error:  Class 'App\Http\Middleware\Auth' not found

Comment: add `use Auth;` top of middlware

Comment: Trying to get property 'admin' of non-object

Comment: plz look at this paste.ofcode.org/ryKDKrs32PUwVq7L5nFLqt

Comment: remember I created a new middleware for it.

Comment: change your Condition

Comment: Call to a member function send() on boolean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194657/discussion-between-programmer0001-and-spyker).

Answer (score 1):

you can use laravel middleware

URL : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware
or https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_middleware.htm

and use to route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'isAdmin'], function(){
    Route::get('user', 'user\UserController@index');
});
```

Comment: m also using middleware but unable to use Route::resource('file','FileController'); in right way??

Comment: add middleware example Admin to middleware folder and Route::get('/', function () {
       return view('welcome');
     })->middleware('admin');

Comment: Route [file.index] not defined

Comment: plz look at this   paste.ofcode.org/ryKDKrs32PUwVq7L5nFLqt

Comment: add middleware to app/http/Kernel.php => $routeMiddleware=[..., 'isAdmin'=> YOURMiddleware ]

Comment: type of Auth::user()->admin is string or int , not bool

Comment: use if(Auth::user()->admin=='1')